Cannot disable Quick Note
I'm unable to disable Quick Note in the bottom right corner. I've disabled all hot corners and rebooted my machine. I'm using Sonoma 14.5. Any ideas?


Ensure all hot corners are set to "None" in System Settings > Desktop & Dock. Also, go to System Settings > Notes and disable any Quick Note options.

Thank you! I understand it now. Apparently, there are two hot corner menus, and I used the wrong one under Accessibility.
